# How do I install drivers for the Panasonic MB1900CX All-in-One Printer/Scanner?

Tags: printing, sane

I bought a new Panasonic Printer/Scanner/Copier,

I am going to to install it, but Ubuntu cant find It`s driver!

I find a driver in Panasonic website but it is 32bit and can not run in my laptop! (my laptop is 64bit!

32bit driver: http://panasonic.net/pcc/support/fax/common/table/linuxdriver.html

I have installed ia32-libs but it Shows same error, the package is build for i686 cpu, can not install to x86_64 system

How can i solve this  problem?

Comment: i found the 64bit version of driver here: http://panasonic.net/pcc/support/fax/common/table/linuxdriver.html#PD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Installing the 64-bit printer driver:

You can download it from [the Panasonic webpage](http://panasonic.net/pcc/support/fax/common/table/linuxdriver.html) you linked. Here's how to install the 64-bit driver:

- Open a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`, and type/paste the following line-by-line:

  ```
  wget -O- http://cs.psn-web.net/support/fax/common/file/Linux_PrnDriver/Driver_Install_files/mccgdi-2.0.3-x86_64.tar.gz | tar -xz
  cd mccgdi-2.0.3-x86_64
  sudo ./install-driver
  ```
- You should see output like the below, after which the driver will be installed. Once it's working, you can renmove the `mccgdi...` folder from Nautilus.

  ```
  start  install......
  start install files......
  restart spooler - CUPS

  Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
  utility, e.g. service cups restart

  Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
  Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,
  e.g. stop cups ; start cups. The restart(8) utility is also available.
  cups stop/waiting
  cups start/running, process 2824

  install driver completed

  please use "system-config-printer" or "lpadmin" to add printer
  ```

#### 2. Installing the 32-bit scanner driver on 64-bit Ubuntu

- There is no guarantee this will actually work, since I don't have a MB1900CX to test it...
- You have already installed `ia32-libs` so you shouldn't need the following, but if `dpkg` complains trying to install the scanner drivers, you should do the following in a terminal:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gcc-4.6-base:i386 libc6:i386 libgcc1:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386
  ```
- Download the 32-bit Panasonic *libsane* driver with:

  ```
  wget http://cs.psn-web.net/support/fax/common/file/Linux_ScanDriver/libsane-panamfs-1.0.0-i386.deb
  ```
- And install it with:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i libsane-panamfs-1.0.0-i386.deb
  ```
- If all goes well, you will see output like the below, and your scanner functions should also work:

  ```
  Selecting previously unselected package libsane-panamfs:i386.
  (Reading database ... 150731 files and directories currently installed.)
  Unpacking libsane-panamfs:i386 (from libsane-panamfs-1.0.0-i386.deb) ...
  Setting up libsane-panamfs:i386 (1.0.0-2) ...
  ```